# Error in connection to database 

Tags: c#, error-handling, sql-server-ce, database-connection

The following code gives an error during execution.

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=D:\\Base.sdf;Persist Security Info=False";
SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) 
sqlConnection.Open();
```

The error is:

> *A network-related or instance-specific error occured while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL server is not configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider:SQL network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error locating
>   Server/Instance Specified)*

I tried `SqlCeConnection` instead of `SqlConnection` but, the compiler couldn't find the library with that class.

Please, help to solve this problem.

- The OS : Windows 7
- Tool : Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
- Language : C#

Comment: `.sdf` is **definitely** a SQL Server **Compact Edition** (CE) database - so you'll need to make sure you have the necessary assemblies installed in order for `SqlCeConnection` to work. This will **NOT** work with `SqlConnection` !

Comment: What assemblies do I need to install?

Comment: You need the SQL Server CE runtime stuff - check out [Everything SQL Server Compact](http://erikej.blogspot.ch/) - this site has tons of explanations, tutorials, how-tos etc. and will definitely also have the info on what needs to be installed and where to get it from

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your database is a Sql Server compact edition one, you must use :

```
SqlCeConnection sqlConnection = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString);
```

Download the libs from here [Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17876)

1. Add a reference to `System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll` to your project
2. Add this using directive using `System.Data.SqlServerCe;`
3. Use `SqlCeConnection` instead of `SqlConnection`