# c# database connection string

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-ce

I'm fairly new to c# and just now started working with databases. I made a local database in my project folder, when I click properties on the database I get "Connection string" as:

```
Data Source="C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\DataBaseTest\MyDatabase#1.sdf"
```

My question is simple, how do I create a connection string using that line? cause writing this generates an error for some reason.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Data Source="C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio
    2012\Projects\DataBaseTest\MyDatabase#1.sdf");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using a SQL Server Compact edition database and for that you must use `SqlCeConnection` instead of `SqlConnection` (Which is used for SQL Server).

You must also escape the back backslashes in your connection string `\` becomes this `\\` :

```
SqlCeConnection sqlConnection = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=C:\\Users\\Documents\\Visual Studio
2012\\Projects\\DataBaseTest\\MyDatabase#1.sdf");
```

or use a verbatim string :

```
SqlCeConnection sqlConnection = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio
2012\Projects\DataBaseTest\MyDatabase#1.sdf");
```

And if you don't have the necessary libs for using SqlCe in your projects refer to my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12157286/162671) :

> Download the libs from here [Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17876)
>
> 1. Add a reference to **`System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll`** to your project
> 2. Add this using directive **`using System.Data.SqlServerCe`**;
> 3. Use **`SqlCeConnection`** instead of **`SqlConnection`**

Comment: Thanks for this info, had no idea :) but when I try to download it I get a message saying I already have a later version (I guess it came with the visual studio) but I still cant refer to it, cause it doesent seem to be in System.Data, any ideas?

Comment: @Jacco look into `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v4.0\Desktop` (for x86) or `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v4.0\Desktop` for x64.

Comment: Its there but how do i refer to it? :/

Comment: @Jacco Right Click on your project inside Visual Studio -> Choose `Add reference` then browse the to the Assembly (System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll)

Comment: @Jacco Maybe you should post that as a new question with the full stack trace of the exception and the new code you're using for the connection.

Comment: You'r probably right, will do and once again thanks alot for all help.

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape backslashes (replace backslashes by double backslashes) or put an @ in front of your string to tell C# to take it literally, like so:

```
new SqlConnection("C:\\Users\\...")
```

or

```
new SqlConnection(@"C:\Users\...")
```

Answer (score 3):

For path you can't add backslashes just like that . You need to escape backslashes . There are two ways

to escape backslash

Method #1 - Use @ in the beginning of the path string

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio
    2012\Projects\DataBaseTest\MyDatabase#1.sdf");
```

Method #2 - add  double backslashes instead of one backslashes

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=C:\\Users\\Documents\\Visual Studio
    2012\\Projects\\DataBaseTest\\MyDatabase#1.sdf");
```

Comment: Thanks for all the quick answers! :) seems to work without any error, but when I run my code and tries to input stuff in the database using a simple form and a button I get this error on that same line:

"Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0."

Any idea what that means?

Comment: Please ref http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9040266/how-to-fix-error-format-of-the-initialization-string-does-not-conform-to-speci

Answer (score 2):

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio
    2012\Projects\DataBaseTest\MyDatabase#1.sdf");
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the @ symbol to show that the string is literal, and ignore special characters.

This page shows samples
http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-literal

Answer (score 0):

For Local Database in Visual Studio 2012, `System.Data.SqlServerCe` needs to be imported in the code. I created a console application which will connect to local database that i added from solution explorer tab and the code will look like

```
SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data ource=C:\Users\MyComputer\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication4\ConsoleApplication4\Database1.sdf");
            con.Open();

        string sql = "SELECT * FROM Employee";//select query
        string sql1 = "INSERT INTO Employee(Name, Age)VALUES('aaa', 12)";//insert query

                SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(sql, con);
                SqlCeCommand cmd1 = new SqlCeCommand(sql1, con);
                cmd1.ExecuteScalar(); // executing insert command
                SqlCeDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();//to read data from table
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}", reader[0],reader[1]));
                }
               con.Close();
```