# C# SQL Server database connection string syntax errors

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I'm very new to C# so I'm using tutorials to get by.

I'm following a youtube tutorial on creating a login form. Linked [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QmT1oec1YBc), at 10:00 mins into the video he starts inputting a connection string which was retrieved from the database earlier.

I followed the exact same steps inputting the following:

```
SqlConnection connnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="C: \Users\Kevin\source\repos\Kops' Toolbox\Kops' Toolbox\Database1.mdf";Integrated Security=True");
```

However, I was surprised to see 26 errors all to do with that line. I suspected it was something to do with the string, as I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892760/c-sharp-database-connection-string) that

> You must also escape the back backslashes in your connection string \ becomes this \\

However, by using the `@` symbol before the string it turns into a `verbatim string` as I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16635176/what-is-a-verbatim-string) so that isn't the problem.

Now, I'm assuming that the issue lies with my `app.config` as in other posts I've seen them add their connection string there, and then create a new connection string referencing that, but in the listed tutorial he doesn't do this, which leaves me confused.

App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Login button

```
private void buttonLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection connnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="C: \Users\Kevin\source\repos\Kops' Toolbox\Kops' Toolbox\Database1.mdf";Integrated Security=True");

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select count(*) from login where Username ='" + textBoxUsername.Text + "' and Password='" + textBoxPassword.Text + "'", connnection);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);

    if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
    {
        LoginSuccess();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Failed login.");
    }
}
```

Error messages

> Error CS1003  Syntax error, ',' expected  Kops' Toolbox   C:\Users\Kevin\source\repos\Kops' Toolbox\Kops' Toolbox\Form1.cs    62  Active
>   Error CS1009  Unrecognized escape sequence    Kops' Toolbox   C:\Users\Kevin\source\repos\Kops' Toolbox\Kops' Toolbox\Form1.cs    62  Active
>   Error CS1056  Unexpected character '\'    Kops' Toolbox   C:\Users\Kevin\source\repos\Kops' Toolbox\Kops' Toolbox\Form1.cs    62  Active
>   Error CS1003  Syntax error, ',' expected  Kops' Toolbox   C:\Users\Kevin\source\repos\Kops' Toolbox\Kops' Toolbox\Form1.cs    62  Active
>   Error CS1056  Unexpected character '\'    Kops' Toolbox   C:\Users\Kevin\source\repos\Kops' Toolbox\Kops' Toolbox\Form1.cs    62  Active
>   Error CS1003  Syntax error, ',' expected  Kops' Toolbox   C:\Users\Kevin\source\repos\Kops' Toolbox\Kops' Toolbox\Form1.cs    62  Active
>   Error CS1056  Unexpected character '\'    Kops' Toolbox   C:\Users\Kevin\source\repos\Kops' Toolbox\Kops' Toolbox\Form1.cs    62  Active
>   Error CS1003  Syntax error, ',' expected  Kops' Toolbox   C:\Users\Kevin\source\repos\Kops' Toolbox\Kops' Toolbox\Form1.cs    62  Active
>   Error CS1056  Unexpected character '\'    Kops' Toolbox   C:\Users\Kevin\source\repos\Kops' Toolbox\Kops' Toolbox\Form1.cs    62  Active
>   Error CS1003  Syntax error, ',' expected  Kops' Toolbox   C:\Users\Kevin\source\repos\Kops' Toolbox\Kops' Toolbox\Form1.cs    62  Active
>   Error CS1003  Syntax error, ',' expected  Kops' Toolbox   C:\Users\Kevin\source\repos\Kops' Toolbox\Kops' Toolbox\Form1.cs    62  Active
>   Error CS1012  Too many characters in character literal    Kops' Toolbox   C:\Users\Kevin\source\repos\Kops' Toolbox\Kops' Toolbox\Form1.cs    62  Active
>   Error CS1009  Unrecognized escape sequence    Kops' Toolbox   C:\Users\Kevin\source\repos\Kops' Toolbox\Kops' Toolbox\Form1.cs    62  Active
>   Error CS1003  Syntax error, ',' expected  Kops' Toolbox   C:\Users\Kevin\source\repos\Kops' Toolbox\Kops' Toolbox\Form1.cs    62  Active
>   Error CS1056  Unexpected character '\'    Kops' Toolbox   C:\Users\Kevin\source\repos\Kops' Toolbox\Kops' Toolbox\Form1.cs    62  Active
>   Error CS1003  Syntax error, ',' expected  Kops' Toolbox   C:\Users\Kevin\source\repos\Kops' Toolbox\Kops' Toolbox\Form1.cs    62  Active
>   Error CS1003  Syntax error, ',' expected  Kops' Toolbox   C:\Users\Kevin\source\repos\Kops' Toolbox\Kops' Toolbox\Form1.cs    62  Active
>   Error CS1739  The best overload for 'SqlConnection' does not have a parameter named 'C'   Kops' Toolbox   C:\Users\Kevin\source\repos\Kops' Toolbox\Kops' Toolbox\Form1.cs    62  Active
>   Error CS0103  The name 'Users' does not exist in the current context  Kops' Toolbox   C:\Users\Kevin\source\repos\Kops' Toolbox\Kops' Toolbox\Form1.cs    62  Active
>   Error CS0103  The name 'Kevin' does not exist in the current context  Kops' Toolbox   C:\Users\Kevin\source\repos\Kops' Toolbox\Kops' Toolbox\Form1.cs    62  Active
>   Error CS1738  Named argument specifications must appear after all fixed arguments have been specified. Please use language version 7.2 or greater to allow non-trailing named arguments.  Kops' Toolbox   C:\Users\Kevin\source\repos\Kops' Toolbox\Kops' Toolbox\Form1.cs    62  Active
>   Error CS0103  The name 'source' does not exist in the current context Kops' Toolbox   C:\Users\Kevin\source\repos\Kops' Toolbox\Kops' Toolbox\Form1.cs    62  Active
>   Error CS0103  The name 'repos' does not exist in the current context  Kops' Toolbox   C:\Users\Kevin\source\repos\Kops' Toolbox\Kops' Toolbox\Form1.cs    62  Active
>   Error CS0103  The name 'Kops' does not exist in the current context   Kops' Toolbox   C:\Users\Kevin\source\repos\Kops' Toolbox\Kops' Toolbox\Form1.cs    62  Active
>   Error CS0103  The name 'Toolbox' does not exist in the current context    Kops' Toolbox   C:\Users\Kevin\source\repos\Kops' Toolbox\Kops' Toolbox\Form1.cs    62  Active
>   Error CS0103  The name 'Database1' does not exist in the current context  Kops' Toolbox   C:\Users\Kevin\source\repos\Kops' Toolbox\Kops' Toolbox\Form1.cs    62  Active

Database, named `Database1` table is called `UserData`

[image]

Comment: [Can I escape a double quote in a verbatim string literal?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1928909)

Comment: try this : "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=\"C:\\Users\\Kevin\\source\\repos\\Kops\' Toolbox\\Kops\' Toolbox\\Database1.mdf\";Integrated Security=True";

Comment: I recommend you use ORM tools like entity framework

Comment: you have some major space after `c:`

Comment: @TS The connections string is copied and pasted, that space was there.  I also tried removing the space and running it to no avail.

Comment: Look, you have some serious issues in your connection string. Try this `@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=""C:\Users\Kevin\source\repos\Kops\Toolbox\KopsToolbox\Database1.mdf"";Integrated Security=True"`.  I don't know if this part is correct -- `C:\Users\Kevin\source\repos\Kops\Toolbox\KopsToolbox\Database1.mdf`. If anything, get correct path and paste there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nearly there. The main problem is that your string contains double-quotes; but a string itself is delimited by double-quotes, so you need to 'escape' that character (despite that the accepted answer linked question on verbatim strings doesn't mention that - I will add a comment, but the other answer mentions it).

You should be able to see that it's not right by the colouring of the source in your editor. If you can't, then get a better editor.

The way of escaping this varies between normal strings and verbatim strings. With verbatim strings, just double-up the double-quote like this:

```
SqlConnection connnection = new SqlConnection(
    @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=""C:\Users\Kevin\source\repos\Kops' Toolbox\Kops' Toolbox\Database1.mdf"";Integrated Security=True");
```

(I removed the space after `C:`)

Extra tips:

- SqlConnection and SqlDataAdapter (and SqlCommand, for future reference) are IDisposable, so should be in `using` blocks.
- This code is vulnerable to Sql injection attack - please read up about that once you've got this working.
- You only need the first value from the first row, so try creating an SqlCommand, and use ExecuteScalar.